Extending pairwise beam splitters operators to an overall transformation
Let $\bar x_s, \sigma_s$ be the vector of first moments and the covariance matrix of an $N$-mode Gaussian state $\rho_s$. If $\rho_s$ is paired with an empty environment of similar dimension, the total state is described by the moments
\begin{equation}
    \bar x = \begin{pmatrix}
        \bar x_s \\ 0_{\scriptstyle{N}}
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad \sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma_s & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_e
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_e = \frac12 I_{2N}$.
Now consider the action of a family of beam splitters $\{S_j\}$ coupling each system mode $j$ with the corresponding $j$-th environmental mode with transmittance $\sqrt{t_j}$ and reflectivity $r_j$. Since we are only interested in the system, we take the partial trace right after the transformation, in order to obtain $\bar x_s'$ and $\sigma_s'$.
My question is: what is the correct expression for the evolved subsystem? My main doubt arises from the way I should be writing the total transformation $S$. Each beam splitter mixing two modes can be individually written as a matrix
$$S_j = \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{t_j}I_2 & \sqrt{r_j}I_2 \\ -\sqrt{r_j}I_2 & \sqrt{t_j}I_2\end{pmatrix}$$ and I originally wrote $S=\bigoplus_j S_j$, but I think I'm making a mistake since that would correspond to the interleaved ordering of the quadratures $$(q_1^s, p_1^s, q_1^e, p_1^e,..., q_N^s, p_N^s, q_N^e, p_N^e)$$ instead of the ordering $$(q_1^s, p_1^s, ..., q_N^s, p_N^s, q_1^e, p_1^e,...,q_N^e, p_N^e)$$ implied by the original form of $\sigma$. I tried writing down the matrices explicitly for $N=2$ but the corrected version doesn't seem to admit a nice closed form for general $N$, making the computation of the partial trace somewhat harder.

Now consider the general case $\sqrt t_j\in \mathbb C$. Write $\sqrt t_j = |\sqrt t_j|e^{i\phi_j}$; then the total transformation should be equivalent to a phase shift $F = \bigoplus_{j=1}^N R(\phi_j)$ with
$$R(\phi_j) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi_j & \sin\phi_j \\ -\sin\phi_j & \cos\phi_j \end{pmatrix} $$ followed by a pure loss with real transmittances $|\sqrt t_j|$, yielding
$$\sigma_s' = (DF)\sigma(DF)^\top + \frac12(I - D^2)$$
where now we define $D := \text{diag}(|\sqrt t_1|, |\sqrt t_1|,...,|\sqrt t_N|, |\sqrt t_N|)$.

You are essentially asking what happens when a multimode Gaussian states loses photons from each mode, with a different loss probability for each mode?

@QuantumMechanic Yep, basically! Sorry, these are probably standard results, but I'm not very familiar with quantum optics.

Without writing a full answer, I just did this iteratively (doesn't matter to which mode you first apply loss). The "diagonals" of the covariance matrix (involving $p$ and $q$ operators from the same mode) get multiplied by $t_i$ and added to them are a normalized 2x2 identity matrix times $1-t_i$ (same as for single mode loss), while the off diagonals involving $i\neq j$ terms get multiplied by $\sqrt{t_i t_j}$, I believe

@QuantumMechanic Not sure if I understand this correctly; do you mind writing a more fleshed out answer? In my basis I got to $\sigma_s' = D\sigma_s D^\top + \frac12(I_{2N}
-D^2)$, where $$ D:=\text{diag}(\sqrt{t_1}, \sqrt{t_1},..., \sqrt{t_N}, \sqrt{t_N}),$$ but it doesn't seem to match with your comment.

@QuantumMechanic Sorry, of course it is the same, isn't it? I had read your comment wrong. Just not sure what you mean by "normalized identity matrix".

Just the 1/2 factor to make the identity normalized in the same way as the covariance matrix. Some people normalize their covariance matrices differently and that will affect whether it's an identity matrix or something proportional to that

Using formulae from the quick reference, a beam splitter acts with matrix (their $F$ is OP's $S$)
$$S=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{t}{I}_2&\sqrt{r}{I}_2\\-\sqrt{r}{I}_2&\sqrt{t}{I}_2\end{pmatrix}$$ in the basis of $\{q^s,p^s,q^e,p^e\}$. Given that the covariance matrix for those modes begins as a block-diagonal matrix with $\sigma^s$ and $\sigma^e$ on the diagonal, we have the updated covariance matrix $S\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^s &0\\0&\sigma^e\end{pmatrix}S^\dagger=\begin{pmatrix}t \sigma^s+r \sigma^e&\sqrt{tr}(\sigma^e-\sigma^s)\\\sqrt{tr}(\sigma^e-\sigma^s) &r\sigma^s+t\sigma^e\end{pmatrix}$, from which we trace out the environment to find $\sigma^s\to t\sigma^s+r\sigma^e$ (the 0 parts are 0 matrices of appropriate size). What happens to the multimode version?
Acting with a beam splitter on one mode and then tracing out the corresponding environment is an operation that commutes with the same being done on another mode with another environment. As such, we can inspect the individual action of each of these operations and put them together to achieve the cumulative action.
When this individual operation acts on a multimode system, it is convenient to include only the one environment and perform this operation on the final mode; the rest will be taken care of accordingly. Since it leaves the other modes unchanged, we write
$$S_N=\begin{pmatrix}I_{2N-2}&0&0\\
0&\sqrt{t_N}{I}_2&\sqrt{r_N}{I}_2\\0&-\sqrt{r_N}{I}_2&\sqrt{t_N}{I}_2\end{pmatrix}$$ in the basis of $\{q_1^s,p_1^s,q_2^s,p_2^s,q_3^s,p_3^s\cdots,q_N^s,p_N^s,q_N^e,p_N^e\}$. Act with this one the covariance matrix of the system and its one environment $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^s&0\\0&\sigma^e\end{pmatrix},$ where we break $\sigma^s=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B^\dagger&C\end{pmatrix}$ into blocks of size $2N-2\times 2N-2$, $2N-2\times 2$, and $2\times 2$ for $A,B,C$ respectively. Then
\begin{equation}
S_N \Sigma S_N^\dagger=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 A & B \sqrt{t_N} & -B \sqrt{r_N} \\
 B^\dagger \sqrt{t_N} & C t_N+r_N \sigma^e & \sqrt{r_N} \sqrt{t_N} \left(\sigma^e-C\right) \\
 -B^\dagger \sqrt{r_N} & \sqrt{r_N} \sqrt{t_N} \left(\sigma^e-C\right) & C r_N+t_N \sigma^e \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation} and ignoring the environment yields
\begin{equation}
\sigma^s=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B^\dagger &C\end{pmatrix}\to\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 A & B \sqrt{t_N}  \\
 B^\dagger \sqrt{t_N} & C t_N+r_N \sigma^e  \\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation} What is the upshot? After mode $N$ has this operation, the $2\times 2$ part of the covariance matrix corresponding to that mode gets multiplied by $t_N$ and then $r_N I_2/2$ is added to it. As well, all of the off-diagonal components of the covariance matrix with one of the indices corresponding to either $q^s_N$ or $p^s_N$ get multiplied by $\sqrt{t_N}$. The same will occur when any of the other modes has this operation.
Indeed, collecting the results, the covariance matrix of the system transforms as
$$\sigma^s\to D\sigma^s D^\dagger+(I_{2N}-D^2)/2$$ for $D=\text{diag}(\sqrt{t_1},\sqrt{t_1},\sqrt{t_2},\sqrt{t_2},\cdots,\sqrt{t_N},\sqrt{t_N})$. Each diagonal $2\times 2$ block gets updated is it would in the absence of other modes, while each off-diagonal block gets multiplied by a corresponding $\sqrt{t_i t_j}$.

Thanks, I upvoted the answer even if it won't show for a while. I'd like to ask a continuation of this question, about the case where $\sqrt t_i$ is allowed to take on a complex value, but that may be worth another post.

@PhilK. good question. For the diagonal blocks nothing will change. For the off diagonals you can just go through the matrix multiplication and see what happens. Probably just needs $D$ to be complex.

Yes, at a glance I think it should be enough to write $DD^\dagger$ instead of $D^2$. Let me know if you agree!

@PhilK. my bad, we don't need complex conjugation anywhere here. When using $q$ and $p$ everything is real and we just need transposes and no conjugate transposes. Now if you ask what happens for beam splitters with different phases, check the quick reference, all extra phase shifts act as (real) rotations in one mode on $q$ and $p$. What's nice is that loss is not affected by these phase shifts, so once you ignore the environment nothing will change in the results

Again, I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I think it is a symptom of discussing things in the comments: I have added my own answer to the general case above, would you mind checking if it matches with your own?

@PhilK. $S$ should only have real parameters, even if the beam splitter is complex

Agreed, it should look something like $$S_j = \begin{bmatrix}
| \tau_j|R(\phi_j) & \sqrt{1-|\tau_j|^2}R(\phi_j) \
-\sqrt{1-|\tau_j|^2}R(\phi_j) & |\tau_j|R(-\phi_j)
\end{bmatrix} $$ or equivalently a phase shift followed by pure loss in each mode, matching my update in the question. Correct?
